# discord.js embeds not working through a command handler

Tags: discord.js

So im new to coding a discord bot and have been watching CodeLyons tutorials.
Im quite Confused As My Embeds Wont Work Through The Command Handler, Someone Help Please.

My embed is pretty simple and is shown working through the command handler in the tutorials
my command prompt error is shown here:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (J:\J_Desktop\discord\DiscordBot\main.js:32:37)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (J:\J_Desktop\discord\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (J:\J_Desktop\discord\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (J:\J_Desktop\discord\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (J:\J_Desktop\discord\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (J:\J_Desktop\discord\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (J:\J_Desktop\discord\DiscordBot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (J:\J_Desktop\discord\DiscordBot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:797:20)
```

Bot File:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Client = new Discord.Client();
const token = ''
const prefix = '¬';

const fs = require('fs');

Client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    Client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

Client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Online');
});

Client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'ping') {
        Client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'rick') {
        Client.commands.get('rickroll').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'embed') {
        Client.commands.get('embed').execute(message, args, Discord);
    }
});

Client.login(token);
```

Command File

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'Embedded Rickroll',
    description: 'Nil',
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        const newEmbed = new Discord.messageEmbed()
        .setColor('#00CED1')
        .setTitle('You Know The Rules, And So Do I!')
        .setURL('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ')
        .setDescription('Were No Strangers To Love')
        .addImage('https://i.imgur.com/dVz9Iuc.png')
        .setFooter('Im So Sorry');

        message.channel.send(newEmbed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your module's name is `Embedded Rickroll`, trying to execute `rickroll` is returning undefined because they're both different names.

Comment: Ah Thanks The Command works now just gotta fix the actual embed